# Exclude ES6 Imports from Istanbul Code Coverage Reports

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, code-coverage, istanbul, karma-coverage

"Is there a way to exclude ES6 imports from Istanbul code coverage reports?

This is a snapshot of a sample report generated. [snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOOFf.png)

Using the following setup:

- "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^2.0.0"
- "karma": "^1.5.0"
- "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0"
- "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1"
- "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.3.0"
- "karma-mocha": "^1.3.0"
- "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.2.2"
- "karma-sinon-chai": "^1.2.4"
- "karma-webpack": "^2.0.2"
- "mocha": "^3.2.0""

Comment: Are you using Webpack 2 or Babel to implement the imports?

Comment: "I'm using Webpack 2"